# Hide the social media links: "Share a link to Google+, Twitter, or Facebook"

Tags: discussion

I'm not active on social media so the chance of sharing a Stack Overflow question on Google+, Twitter, or Facebook is approximately zero.

When I do share a post, the quieter "share" link alongside "edit", "close" and "flag" buttons is working just fine.

[image: Screenshot of the social media links with a big red circle around them and a handwritten 'No'.]

**How to hide those "share" links and see a less noisy UI?**

Comment: Some analytics on whether those buttons are used would be nice to check the hypothesis that these are not used by the majority in comparison to the "share" button and can thus be removed. I also never used any of them, just the "share" button.

Comment: Honestly why anyone would use these and not just send a link is beyond me.  I appreciate the answers below but the real answer should be a "dismiss" hyperlink that is at least cookie'd and zap these gone.

Comment: @JonH totally agreed.

Comment: Is Google+ still a thing?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, Google+ is still active. I think it's still linked to YouTube.

Comment: @BSMP I don't think a link between a Google+ and YouTube account is mandatory anymore.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use clientside javascript to remove the "bottom-share-links" from the website:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wimglenn/userscripts/master/stackoverflow.com/social-notworking.user.js

Instructions how to apply userscripts (chrome/tampermonkey) are here:

https://github.com/wimglenn/userscripts/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Turns out some ad-blockers are effective in that same area: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258535/158100

Comment: The name is just hilarious.

Comment: Meh I'll resort to @wim's user script - gracias!

Answer (score 22):

I believe this stuff can be safely removed from the site for everyone.

Is anyone really so passionate about SO that if they find a question they can't answer, they go through their professional network to see if anyone they know can? I don't really see myself sending a message through e-mail or social media:

> Hi x, I found a question on SO about y. I can't answer it, but I know you are an expert of the topic. There has been no answers so far, so I thought maybe you could help this guy out?

They would wonder if I'm drunk or high.

So can we just remove the whole thing? Since it is just waste of space for everyone, regardless of how active they are on social media.

Comment: I see people doing this for their own questions often enough, and I could theoretically imagine it for a question that they need solved, but that someone else already asked (and didn't get answered), although I've never seen that personally.  So even if you care about that, you could show it only for the author of the question, not anyone else.

Comment: @Servy If you know someone IRL who can answer, such as a colleague, then you go and ask them. You don't post it on the internet and then send a note to said colleague over social media. That would just be strange and awkward behavior.

Comment: You can know someone other than a colleague who can answer.  Why is asking your friends and associates on a social media platform for help with a programming problem any more strange than asking strangers on the internet for help with a programming problem?

Comment: @Servy Because you posted it on the internet before asking? It's like posting pictures of your failed attempts to repair your car on the internet, then afterwards send a Facebook notification to your friend the car mechanic. Maybe not awkward behavior to the Facebook generation, but quite awkward to the less narcissistic ones. Who would just pick up the phone and call the car mechanic right away, or talk to him in person. Without "the world must learn what I ate for lunch" step in between.

Comment: So you're just opposed to using social media *in general*, and prefer other forms of communication.  That's fine.  No one is forcing you to use social media.  But other people do like to use it.  You're going to need to learn to live with the fact that that's the world we live in today, where lots of people like using social media platforms.  Also there's a problem with your'e story.  You're assuming that there's exactly one person you're looking to help you on this social media platform, and you're using it instead of talking to just them.  What if you have lots of people who might help?

Comment: @Servy No the point is: if you know these people then why did you post on SO?

Comment: Maybe no one you know will actually know the answer (or decide to take the time to answer it).  Maybe someone on SO will have a better answer.  Maybe they want the answer posted to be available publicly for any other programmers to be able to benefit from, rather than staying in a private social network.  Maybe the social media platform isn't well suited for longer questions with code in them, as it doesn't have the proper formatting tools for such a question or its answers.

Comment: But the point is, why are you so opposed to people linking to SO questions from social media platforms?  It's not for you.  That's fine.  It doesn't have to be.  What's wrong with other people doing it?

Comment: @Servy I'm not opposed to it, but rather the text which says "know somebody who can answer?".  **What I'm primarily against is distracting clutter between the question and the box where we type the answer**. We write countless long-winded meta posts about distracting clutter in questions, but are apparently fine with clutter on the site itself. That being said, if you can't manage to copy pasta a URL from SO into an e-mail or social media without being spoon-fed some link, you probably don't belong on a computer programming site to begin with...

Answer (score 19):

If you're running AdBlock, you can visit a page with the links and go to *block an ad on this page* then select the area it appears in and block it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For Adblock Plus, the filter `stackoverflow.com##.bottom-notice.bottom-share-links` works for me